# Actionscript to c#

Tags: c#, actionscript

How to write this in C#.NET, I have not been encountered using the ^ or &

```
var reg_1 = 234 ^ (8393 & 1);
```

Comment: please tell us in english what you want to achieve with your regular expression, this way we don't need to undestand AS regex

Comment: Have you tried looking at the wealth of learning C# material that's out there on the web?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var reg_1 = 234 ^ (8393 & 1);
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
var reg_1 = 235;
```

(If you're not using C#3 then replace `var` with `int`.)

The `^` is the [XOR operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx). The `&` is the [AND operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx).

Comment: @sv88erik: In this context they're bitwise operators. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND